# How to deserialize all Soap serialized objects

Tags: c#, soap-serialization

I am soap serializing multiple objects and appending them to a single file,then I am desirializing to have all the objects to tree view

I am using this part of code of desirialization

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(fName, FileMode.Open);
while (fs.Position < fs.Length)
{
    arraylizt.Add(sf.Deserialize(fs));
}
```

It works well, but sometimes the last object in the file is not desirialized.
I am not getting why its not desirializing the final object sometimes

Please help me or suggest me any other way to deserialize

Comment: can you more code? the problem may appear at a higher level.

Comment: I don't think problem may be in higher level
the following code i am using for serialization

 FileStream fs = new FileStream(fName, FileMode.Append);

            SoapFormatter sf = new SoapFormatter();

            foreach (object item in temp)
            {
                sf.Serialize(fs, item);
            }
            fs.Close();
please help me

Comment: I had gone debug mode and i am seeing file stream position is pointing at the end of file after it deserialize some objects
for ex if a object graph ends at position 82772 but position is pointing 89532 skipping last object to deserialize.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ensure you've flushed your stream upon writing before close (or closed the writer rather than the underlying stream).

Comment: I am not flushed my stream before closing 
r u suggesting wil it solve the problem
if so I will try now....

Comment: It should do, there is a write buffer (as you're using a stream) and it doesn't write until it hit a certain size. Try it!

Comment: I have tried flush before closing stream the problem still remaining

Comment: I had gone debug mode and i am seeing file stream position is pointing at the end of file after it deserialize some objects for ex if a object graph ends at position 82772 but position is pointing 89532 skipping last object to deserialize.